# objective-c - how to convert between signed base 10 numbers and unsigned base 16

Tags: objective-c, radix, unsigned-integer

I am wondering how to do converts between ***unsigned*** base 16 numbers and ***signed*** base 10 numbers?

For example

5d0cfa30041d4348 <-> 6705009029382226760

024025978b5e50d2 <-> 162170919393841362

fb115bd6d34a8e9f <-> -355401917359550817

By the way, they are actually IDs of some items. And internally they are all 64-bit numbers, but in two presentations.

Any classes I can use of ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really have base 10 and 16 numbers, or is that merely the presentation form for binary integers?  (Ie, how are these values typed?)

Comment: Like Daniel said, how are these values stored? Integers are normally stored in binary and rendered at other bases, so if you're storing these some unusual way, we need to know what it is.

Comment: Actually they are strings when I obtain them. They are in a JSON  string from Google Reader. the API explains they are unsigned base 16 and signed base 10. I just need to convert them one to another. The internal for these two forms are 64-bit numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the base 16 value is a constant or stored in a variable a simple cast will work.

```
long long llint1 = (long long int)0x5d0cfa30041d4348;
long long llint2 = (long long int)0x024025978b5e50d2;
long long llint3 = (long long int)0xfb115bd6d34a8e9f;

NSLog(@"\n%lld\n%lld\n%lld", llint1, llint2, llint3);
```

If the value is a string it will just need to be scanned first.

```
unsigned long long tmp;
NSScanner *nscanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0x5d0cfa30041d4348"];
[nscanner scanHexLongLong:&tmp];

llint1 = (long long int)tmp;

nscanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0x024025978b5e50d2"];
[nscanner scanHexLongLong:&tmp];

llint2 = (long long int)tmp;

nscanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0xfb115bd6d34a8e9f"];
[nscanner scanHexLongLong:&tmp];

llint3 = (long long int)tmp;

NSLog(@"\n%lld\n%lld\n%lld", llint1, llint2, llint3);
```

*Note: the `scanHexLongLong` and other scan methods return a BOOL for whether or not the scan was successful. If working with strings it would be best to check that the scan succeeded.*

Comment: thanks. but what if they are actually 64-bit numbers but with two different kinds of forms (one form is unsigned base 16 and the other is signed base 10)?

Comment: @Jackson Tale: Once you've scanned whichever format you have, you can output whichever format you want. If you mean you don't know, given a particular number, which format it's supposed to be in, I'm afraid that's intractable in general — every string representation of a base 10 number is also a valid string representation of a different hexadecimal number. You have to know which kind of number you're scanning. If you know that, just call the appropriate scanning method like Joe showed.